# Google Sheets JScript Row match and delete if - Take rows from Sheet A and delete if identical to rows in Sheet B, Sheet C, Sheet D... etc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My data import (Sheet A) has all information from the last known events. It only changes them when another event occurs. So if the event is from two days ago it is still in my data import (Sheet A) until that event changes. I need to have my data import (Sheet A) checked against Sheet B, Sheet C, and Sheet D for identical rows. Then delete the row if it already exists.

So far I have:

```js
function testFilter() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("SheetA");
var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("SheetB");
var sheetC = ss.getSheetByName("SheetC");
var sheetD = ss.getSheetByName("SheetD");
var sheetE = ss.getSheetByName("SheetE");
var sheetF = ss.getSheetByName("SheetF");

var valuesA = sheetA.getRange('A2:AC400').getValues();
var valuesB = sheetB.getRange('A2:AC400').getValues();
var valuesC = sheetC.getRange('A2:AC400').getValues();
var valuesD = sheetD.getRange('A2:AC400').getValues();
var valuesE = sheetE.getRange('A2:AC400').getValues();
var valuesF = sheetF.getRange('A2:AC400').getValues();

for (var rowa in valuesA)
{
var deleteRowa = false;
  for (var rowb in valuesB)
  {
    if(valuesA[rowa].join() == valuesB[rowb].join())
      deleteRowa = true;
  }
    if(deleteRowa == true){
      sheetA.deleteRow(rowa)
    }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
for (var rowa in valuesA)
{
var deleteRowa = false;
  for (var rowc in valuesC)
  {
    if(valuesA[rowa].join() == valuesC[rowc].join())
      deleteRowa = true;
  }
    if(deleteRowa == true){
      sheetA.deleteRow(rowa)
    }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
for (var rowa in valuesA)
{
var deleteRowa = false;
  for (var rowd in valuesD)
  {
    if(valuesA[rowa].join() == valuesD[rowd].join())
      deleteRowa = true;
  }
    if(deleteRowa == true){
      sheetA.deleteRow(rowa)
    }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
for (var rowa in valuesA)
{
var deleteRowa = false;
  for (var rowe in valuesE)
  {
    if(valuesA[rowa].join() == valuesE[rowe].join())
      deleteRowa = true;
  }
    if(deleteRowa == true){
      sheetA.deleteRow(rowa)
    }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
for (var rowa in valuesA)
{
var deleteRowa = false;
  for (var rowf in valuesF)
  {
    if(valuesA[rowa].join() == valuesF[rowf].join())
      deleteRowa = true;
  }
    if(deleteRowa == true){
      sheetA.deleteRow(rowa)
    }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
```

This gives an Exception: out of bounds error on the first attempt of filtering. Does the deleterows() function work for picking out specific rows? Or am I going to have to throw it into a  new list, then delete all rows from original sheet, then insert the list?

Comment: I don't know why it's out of bounds. But it looks like the algorithm shouldn't work anyway. You remove rows from the SheetA, but you still have the same values in the array `valuesA`. For example, you removed the row 10 from SheetA, but the array `valuesA` still contains all the values. Suppose SheetB has the same values on the row 10. In this case script finds them and tries to remove from the SheetA the row 10 again. Even if the row 10 doesn't contains the same values anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Delete Matching Rows in SheetA

```
function testFilter() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shts = ["SheetB", "SheetC", "SheetD", "SheetE", "SheetF"];
  const A1rg = "A2:AC400";
  let uA = [];//building a unique flat array of row join
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    sh.getRange(A1rg).getValues().forEach(r => {
      let j = r.join("");
      if (!~uA.indexOf(j)) {
        uA.push(j);
      }
    });
  });
  let d = 0;
  const shA = ss.getSheetByName("SheetA");
  shA.getRange(A1rg).getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~uA.indexOf(r.join(""))) {
      shA.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

This version runs quite a bit faster for me

```
function testFilter() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shts = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "SheetD", "SheetE", "SheetF"];
  const A1rg = "A2:AC400";
  let uA = [];
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    sh.getRange(A1rg).getValues().forEach(r => {
      let j = r.join("");
      if (!~uA.indexOf(j)) {
        uA.push(j);
      }
    });
  });
  let d = 0;
  const shA = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  shA.getRange(2, 1, shA.getLastRow() - 1, shA.getLastColumn()).getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~uA.indexOf(r.join(""))) {
      shA.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is about the same algo as Cooper's but, I hope, it's a little bit more readable.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var names = ['SheetA', 'SheetB', 'SheetC', 'SheetD', 'SheetE' ]; // etc

  const get_array_from_sheet = sheet_name => 
    ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name).getRange('A2:AC400').getValues()
    .map(x => x.join('')).filter(String);

  var [sheetA, ...sheets_etc] = names.map(n => get_array_from_sheet(n));

  sheets_etc = sheets_etc.flat();

  var rows_to_delete = sheetA.filter(x => sheets_etc.includes(x))
    .map(x => sheetA.indexOf(x) + 2);

  rows_to_delete.reverse().forEach(x => ss.getSheetByName('SheetA').deleteRow(x));  
}
```